# Ionic app hangs after Splashscreen (real device <IOS9 only)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

we have problems with building our App (www.tasktilldone.com for IOS since the last Xcode update (Version 7+) app.

- simulator for ios 8.1, 8.4, 9.0 --> works
- we tried to run the app on iphone 4s with ios9 --> works
- we tried to run the app on ipad 2 with ios8.1 app hangs after splashscreen main run method in app.js is not even called, index.hml was loaded - fail
- We already installed cordova-plugin-transport-security.

Do you have any ideas, what the problem could be here?

Thank you